# Update UITableView from 3rd container

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

**I have such construction:**

Container Number 1 (FirstViewContainer) with segment control
contains:

Container Number 2 (FoodViewContainer) with another segment control
contains:

Container Number 3 (MyFoodContainer) with UITableView

I need to update UITableView on click from Container Number 1

My code:

CONTAINER 1 ACTION CODE:

```
  @IBAction func nextButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    print("clicked")
    var myClass : FoodViewController = self.children[1] as! FoodViewController

    myClass.relodDatabase()
```

CONTAINER 2 FUNC CODE:

```
func relodDatabase()
{
    print("data reloaded")
    var myClass : MyFoodContainer = self.children[1] as! MyFoodContainer

    myClass.myFoodTable.reloadData()
    if myClass.foodList.count == 0 {
        myClass.myFoodTable.setEmptyView(title: "You don't have any food.", message: "Your food will be in here after adding.")
    }

    else {
        myClass.myFoodTable.restore()
    }

    myClass.viewWillAppear(true)

    var secondClass: CustomFoodContainer = self.children[2] as! CustomFoodContainer

    secondClass.foodList = TrackerDatabase.instance.getFoood(dname: dayTable)
    secondClass.viewWillAppear(true)
}
```

The issue is that nobody happens when I try to reload things.
However, print("data reloaded" executes correct.

The interesting thing, that I can reload table view from 2 containers, one parent, one child.
I cannot do it via parent>child>child's child

Any idea how I can do this correct? Maybe some bypass?

**I included an image:**

On each arrow next to or arrow back, the table should reload, the table is on container number 3.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use protocol or notificationcenter for it. I would prefer protocol if i were you. You can add a delegate that generates from protocol and use it for reloading tableview in first container.